# WebView and javascript

Tags: android

This link:  http://lexandera.com/category/webview_examples/  says you can inject javascript into a web page rendered by a WebView as follows:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
  {  
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
            "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red'; " +  
            "})()");  
  }  
});
```

I want to take it one step further an inject a function that gets executed on key press.

I'm using:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){   

        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
        {  

            webView.loadUrl("javascript:function keyHandler(e) { " +  
               "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red'; " +  
                       "}");                

        }           
    });
```

and the page is already written and includes document.onkeypress = keyHandler which AFAIK should hook up my keyHandler function with any key event occurring on the page.

The problem is, its not working.  I want it to change the text red when a key is pressed.  Instead, the page is rendered and the text turns red BEFORE I press any keys.

Am I misunderstanding how this all works together?

And just so no one things I'm trying to hack something, the whole point of this is to provide custom javascript responses for webpages my employer has created to be rendered in the Android WebView.

Answer (score 0):

with `loadUrl()` you are executing the javascript instead of adding it to the document. what you had to do in the script you're executing is something like

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){   

    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
    {  

        webview.loadUrl("javascript:function() { " +  
           "var script = document.createElement('script'); " +
           "script.innerHTML = 'function keyHandler(e) { document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red'; }'" +
           "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); " +
        "}");                

    }           
});
```

Comment: I don't follow....are you saying I have to: add your posted code to the webpage, define the stuff in between [ ] in the webView.loadUrl() 

and then the web page will automagically call my javascript?

Comment: what you wanna do is to dynamically add the function keyHandler(e) to the document, right? that means that you have to call a javascript function with loadUrl() that does exactly that. see my modified answer. btw: i have not tested that, it's just to give you an idea, so don't shoot me if you copy and past it and it does not run right away.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I think I get it.

I thought all I had to do was define the script in loadUrl().  But in reality, I have to define it and attach it to the page.  Is that the right interpretation?

And I realize there's no warranty on this snippet.  I'm happy enough to talk this stuff out and an example is a bonus.